# How to select the x,z and vx, vz columns list from a 50X6 list in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am loading data that contains 6 elements per line: `(x,y,z,vx,vy,vz)`.

```
data = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/6Werdnpf"];
vecdata = Partition[#, 3] & /@ DeleteDuplicates[data];
```

I am trying to take all the projections on the `x-y, y-z, x-z` planes, but I can't pass `Take` or `Part` the arguments when using it within `Map`.

This will take the component (x,y) and (vx,vy): `Map[Most, vecdata, {2}]`

But I want also to take `y-z`, `x-z` using `Map[Take, vecdata, {2}]`

Comment: Have you considered using another language? Other than than you might want to ask over at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote

```
Map[Most, vecdata, {2}]
```

This is equivalent to the following expressions

```
Map[Part[#, {1, 2}] &, vecdata, {2}]

Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]]} &, vecdata, {2}]

Apply[{#1, #2} &, vecdata, {2}]
```

Your required output can be achieved with

```
xy = Map[Most, vecdata, {2}]

yz = Map[Rest, vecdata, {2}]

xz = Apply[{#1, #3} &, vecdata, {2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

sometimes its good for code readability to do things like this:

```
extractxz[{{x_, y_, z_}, {vx_, vy_, vz_}} ] := {x, z}
extractxz /@ vecdata
```

or without the first partitioning step:

```
extractxz[{x_, y_, z_, vx_, vy_, vz_} ] := {x, z}
extractxz /@ data
```